# Show that if $L=1$, then exists $n_0$ such that $x_n=1, \forall n>n_0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

Let be $x_0,x_1,x_2,\cdots$ a sequence given by

$$x_{n+1}=\dfrac{{x_n}^2}{2}+x_n-\dfrac{1}{2}$$
Suposse that $(x_n)$ is convergent. If $L=\lim x_n$. Show that:

1. $L \in \{-1,1\}$
2. If $L=1$, then exist $n_0 $ such that $x_n=1,\forall n>n_0$.

The part 1. I already made applying limit to the given equality.

I don't know how to show part 2, but I have a few ideas:

- Prove that exist $n_0$ with $x_{n_0}=1$. Because if $x_{n_0}=1$, then $x_n=1, \forall n>n_0$.
- Prove that exist $n_0$ with $x_{n_0}=-3$. Because if $x_{n_0}=-3$, then $x_n=1, \forall n>n_0$.
- as $x_n\to L=1$, then by definitión of limit, $\forall \varepsilon>0,\exists n_{0}\in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n+1>n_0$, $|x_n+3||x_n-1|<\varepsilon$.An idea would be to see how this would imply that $ x_n = 1, \forall n> n_0 $.

One observation I made from the given equality is that $ 2 (x_ {n + 1} +1) = (x_n + 1) ^ 2 $, but I don't know how I could use that to prove what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint.** The sequence is generated by $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$, where $f(x)=\frac{x^2}{2}+x-\frac{1}{2}$, with $f'(x)=x+1$. But $|f'(1)|=2 > 1$, so $L=1$ is a [repelling fixed point](https://www.math.ubc.ca/~andrewr/620341/pdfs/fp_sum.pdf). The only way a sequence will converge to a repelling fixed point is if it's equal to the repelling point, from some $n_0$ onwards.

Alternatively, use the fact that from some $n_0$ onwards
$$1-\varepsilon < x_{n}<1+\varepsilon \Rightarrow
0<\frac{2-\varepsilon}{2} < \frac{1+x_{n}}{2}<\frac{2+\varepsilon}{2}$$
then
$$\left|x_{n+1}-1\right|=
\left|\frac{{x_n}^2}{2}+x_n-1-\dfrac{1}{2}\right|=
|x_n-1|\left|\frac{x_n+1}{2}+1\right|>\\
|x_n-1|\left(\frac{2-\varepsilon}{2}+1\right)>\\
|x_{n-1}-1|\left(\frac{2-\varepsilon}{2}+1\right)^2>...>\\
|x_{n_0}-1|\left(\frac{2-\varepsilon}{2}+1\right)^{n-n_0+1}$$
This can be used to arrive to a contradiction, if we assume that **there is no** such $n_0$ for which $x_n=1$ for $n\geq n_0$, because $\left(\frac{2-\varepsilon}{2}+1\right)^{n-n_0+1} \to\infty, n\to\infty$.